# how to pass null value to just one specific key of the one object using same DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, drf-queryset

I'm just passing the same object 2 times in the same serializer but I want to pass key: "retweet": null in one object and in another object I want to pass some values like some many-to-many field values because key "retweet" is many-to-many field and having data

Thanks in advance!

Comment: share your serializers.py code ?